# Using custom backgrounds for buttons created through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, button, imagebutton

Trying to have a button created in JavaScript to use the background image of the specific API image
I seen many suggestions to use `.style.backgroundImage = 'Url("yourimagelink")';`. But can't seem to figure it out.

Updated to include my function.

```
//  The "addListItem" function creates li and button for item names also creates event on click

function addListItem(item) {
    let groupList = document.querySelector('.list-group');

    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.classList.add('list-group-item');

    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.classList.add('btn-image');
    button.innerText = item.name;
    button.style.backgroundImage = 'Url("item.imageUrl")';

    listItem.appendChild(button);

    groupList.appendChild(listItem);

    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        showDetails(item);
    });
};
```

No image appears and no errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the button to the DOM, using **appendChild** for example, **createElement** only creates the button instance, it is not added to the DOM.

**Working example below:**

```js
item = { name: 'test', imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1446404465118-3a53b909cc82?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=32&w=32&s=a2f8c40e39b8dfee1534eb32acfa6bc7' };

let button = document.createElement('button'); // It only create the button instance, but don't add it to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(button); // You should add the button to the DOM
button.classList.add('btn-image');
button.innerText = item.name;
button.style.backgroundImage = `url(${item.imageUrl})`;
```

Comment: I have updated the question to show my full function, I do append everything, but still have no clue on why the image wont show.

Comment: You are adding the image as string, it will not work:     
`button.style.backgroundImage = 'Url("item.imageUrl")';`

Change to this:
`button.style.backgroundImage = "url("+item.imageUrl+")";`